# Azure DevOps - variable for AzureKeyVault@2

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have written this parameter in Azure DevOps.
The value of the parameter changes based on user input.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: cert_name
    default: some_secret_123
    type: string
```

and this job:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: my_job
    displayName: my_job
    steps:
      - task: AzureKeyVault@2
        displayName: Fetch secret dynamically
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: some_subscription
          KeyVaultName: some_vault
          SecretsFilter: ${{ parameters.cert_name }}
```

Normally, to [view the content of the secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-key-vault-v2?view=azure-pipelines), one could use `$(some_secret_123)`.
But the value of the `cert_name` changes based on user input, so that won't work for my use case.

My goal is to have the value of SecretsFilter as a variable for the AzureKeyVault task, so i can dynamically re-use it for further use.

Is it possible to configure it in such a way, and if so, how.

Comment: Is it possible to configure it the way I want, and if so, how.

Comment: @KevinC As the Shamrai Aleksander shared in the answer,  the format: `$(${{ parameters.cert_name }})` can allow you to use the nested variable in the next tasks. 
Process: `$(${{ parameters.cert_name }}) -> $(cert_namevalue) -> keyvaultvalue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to combine the template expression and environment variables:
[Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables)

Example:

```
parameters:
  - name: cert_name
    default: some_secret_123
    type: string

steps:
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'your_service_connection'
    KeyVaultName: 'your_akv'
    SecretsFilter: '${{ parameters.cert_name }}'
    RunAsPreJob: false

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Hello World $env:MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR"
  env:
    MY_MAPPED_ENV_VAR: $(${{ parameters.cert_name }})
```

Result:

[image]